# Google Drive API

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api

I am trying to integrate Google Drive in my webpage by using the GoogleDrive API. 
I have copied most of the code from google.And  when executing it, I have an issue with the function given. This is my code:

```
    $apiConfig['use_objects'] = true;
session_start();
$url_array = explode('?', 'http://'.$_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url = $url_array[0];
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_Service.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php';


$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('347297625177-l6476q96da6fi65iqp0ra84e3luic5kp.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('8UE-faGCj9xBKe8IsgP0pN2r');
$client->setRedirectUri("http://arodrisa.url.ph/GoogleDrive_example/list.php");
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

echo "5";
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $_SESSION['accessToken'] = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    header('location:'.$url);exit;
} elseif (!isset($_SESSION['accessToken'])) {
    $client->authenticate();
}
echo"2";
$result = array();
$pageToken = NULL;



do {
  try {
    $parameters = array();
    if ($pageToken) {
      $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
    }
    $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
    $list=$files['items'];
    $result = array_merge($result,$list);
    $pageToken = $files['nextPageToken'];
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    $pageToken = NULL;
  }
} while ($pageToken);
    var_dump($result);
    include 'list.html';
```

I get this error:

> 52 Fatal error: Call to a member function listFiles() on a non-object in /home/u317564784/public_html/GoogleDrive_example/list.php on line 39

Which referes to this line:

```
 $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
```

Please help me.

Comment: Where are you assigning `$service`? https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php

Comment: No, that solves the problem.

Comment: SOLVED I have added these lines

$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
before

 $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

Comment: It's good to see you solved your problem, but consider adding your fix as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED I have added these lines

```
   $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']); 
   $service = new Google_DriveService($client); 
   $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
   $file = new Google_DriveFile();
```

before

```
   $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
```

Comment: getting PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function finfo_open() .. ??